# Pascal's Triangle - algorithm works in C++ but got 'Time Limit Exceeded' in java

Tags: java, algorithm, pascals-triangle

A leetcode problem: Given numRows, generate the first numRows of Pascal's triangle.

The C++ version of this algorithm got accepted by Leetcode. Could anyone tell me why this Java version cannot get accepted?

```
    public class Solution {

    public List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {

    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    if (numRows == 0) return result;

    List<Integer> raw = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    raw.add(1);
    result.add(raw);
    if (numRows == 1) return result;

    List<Integer> row  = raw;
    List<Integer> row2 = raw;
    for (int i = 2; i <= numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row.size()-1; j++)
            row2.add(row.get(j) + row.get(j+1));
        row2.add(1);
        result.add(row2);
        row = row2;
        row2 = raw;
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Where did the time limit come from?

Comment: It's from the LeetCode Online Judge.

Comment: You only have one instance of List<Integer> in the entire nested for loop. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could anyone tell me why this Java version cannot get accepted?

Because your code runs forever.

You have **exactly one** `List<Integer>` and it keeps growing:

```
for (int j = 0; j < row.size()-1; j++)
        row2.add(row.get(j) + row.get(j+1));
```

In each iteration you move one element forward and add one element, **to the same list**, essentially eternally chasing the end that keeps getting away.

*(I had a friend at uni who initially also didn't understand how references work in Java and made a similar mistake with Lists. He got like a bazillion buttons in a Swing GUI.)*